# Remove filtered out elements from ArrayCollection in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, arraycollection

I have a big ArrayCollection variable.
I want to filter it several times and each time assign the filtered result to a different ArrayCollection variable.

So if it has let's say people, fruits and cars. (for illustration purposes)
I want to first filter it to only show people, assign the result to a people ArrayCollection, then filter it to show fruits and assign it to a fruits ArrayCollection and so on.

How can I do that? Not the filtering, but the assignment after filtering.
Or is it faster to instead run a for-loop through the big ArrayCollection and just add each item into the corresponding smaller ArrayCollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`mx.collections.ListCollectionView`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html) for that. Say you have the following original `ArrayCollection`:

```
var myCollection:ArrayCollection;
```

Now people:

```
var peopleList:ListCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(myCollection);
peopleList.filterFuntion = peopleFilterFuntion;
peopleList.refresh();
```

The same for fruits:

```
var fruitsList:ListCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(myCollection);
fruitsList.filterFuntion = fruitsFilterFuntion;
fruitsList.refresh();
```

And cars:

```
var carsList:ListCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(myCollection);
carsList.filterFuntion = carsFilterFuntion;
carsList.refresh();
```

Comment: Aren't the filtered out variables kept in memory for when the filterFunction is set to null?

Comment: As far as I know, `ListCollectionView` doesn't create new underlying collection but uses the original `ArrayCollection`. So it doesn't occupy extra memory for elements.